# How to fix "your api request count has exceeded?" for tmdb.org?

Tags: android

My code was working fine initially, then All of a sudden I'm not able to display posters on my app. I'm getting this particular error.
I've removed almost all while(true) loops. Please help.

Comment: My gitHub repo: https://github.com/Amisha95/MyStage2Project

Comment: That error message seems clear that you've exceeded the documented limit of requests

Comment: Apparently the problem is because of too many API calls. Can someone tell me a way to reduce it and how? @cricket_007 I want to know the way to fix it.

Comment: One way is that every time you make a request to `URLString = "http://api.themoviedb.org/3/movie/" + ids.get(i) + "/videos?api_key=" + API_KEY;`, you may want to cache that result for a period of time. Unless you expect that dataset to change very frequently, you only need that JSON response once, then you can process it repeatedly later to extract the data you need without making another network request.

Answer (score 0):

You are probably making too many API requests.

From the [TMDB.org FAQ](https://www.themoviedb.org/faq/api):

> We currently rate limit requests to 30 requests every 10 seconds.

You should make sure your app never uses more than that. How you implement this is up to you, but you could keep track of a request counter that:

- decrements every time you make a request
- resets to 30 or so every ten seconds
- only allows requests to continue if it is positive

In general, you should try to query the API as little as possible: cache results in your app as much as you can.

Comment: Luckily, by the date I am writing this comment, there is no more rate limit!